# Execute a query on Database link using Java Program

Tags: java, sql, database, oracle

I have two Databases on different interconnected computers and databases are connected via a database link. I am using oracle 10g

I am trying to execute a query from java

```
select * from customer@link1;
```

But I am not getting the desired results.

Java codes, I am using to get the data is as below:

```
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
               con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521:XE","checkerchief","1234");
                st=con.createStatement();

                String q = "select * from customer@pooja";
                System.out.println(q);
                rs=st.executeQuery(q);
                meta=rs.getMetaData();
                cols=meta.getColumnCount();
                col=new String[cols];
                for(int i=0;i<cols;i++)
                {
                    col[i]=new String();
                    col[i]=meta.getColumnName(i+1);
                }
                rows=0;
                while(rs.next())
                    rows++;

                rs=st.executeQuery("Select * from "+s);
                data=new String[rows][cols];
```

Please let me know, what is the issue here.

Comment: Do you get an Exception? If yes, could you post it?

Comment: Is it a public link? Or if not are you sure user checkerchief is the owner of the link?

Comment: Fixed title text, body content